# How To: VS C# App Option to connect to various data sources?

Tags: c#, database

I am currently writing a program in C# that will connect to a database for various user data. The query I have at the moment is what would be the best practice to be able to connect to various databases from the program at runtime?

To clarify:
I may want to connect to Oracle R12, or MS SQL Server or maybe even a dumb old access database. I am fine with putting the connection methods into their respective classes, but what I really want is a config file to be packaged with the application which dictates the type of server used for each installation, the field naming convention, etc.

So should this connection file be a .dll? an encrypted text file? or something else?
Obviously I dont want the end user ready access to the connection details in case they try and do their own digging in the database outside of my application.

Comment: Putting this into a `.dll` is **barely** obfuscation. I'd bet that your connection strings would be present inside the DLL as UTF-16 text or something.

Comment: Also, what exactly is your question? You already know two ways to store this, so pick whichever one suits your needs. It's up to you to decide how much complexity you're willing to add to your app in order to deter an attacker. (Knowing that on a PC there's really no way to do this perfectly.)

Comment: Encrypt your strings your app.config.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with encrypted configuration section, it's pretty standard and there are many examples, here is MS documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx